# How multiple task can add values to an concurrent queue

Tags: c#, .net

I'm struggling with multiple task adding  integeres to concurrent queue. I have seen a few tutorials but I found them quite complicatated.  Also, I want to do this because I want to implement the consumer-producer problem.

this what I've been trying to do

```
class Program
    {
        const int MAX_VALUE = 20;
        const int valueP = 0;
         static BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>(new ConcurrentQueue<int>(), 20 );

        static void producer(int value)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++)
            {
                bc.Add(value);

                value++;
                Console.WriteLine( value);
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        static void consuemr()
        {
            int item = 0;
            item = bc.Take();
            Console.WriteLine("An item has been consumed", item);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task t1 =Task.Run(() => producer(valueP));
            Task t2 = Task.Run(() => producer(valueP));

            Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
            Task.Run(() =>consuemr());


        }
       }
```

but things stop working when its time to led the consumer

Comment: You make a static ConcurrentQueue, and then you add stuff to it (like in a Parallel.For(0,int.MaxValue,i=> { myConcurrentQueue.Enqueue(i);}); That's all there is to it. If you'd like to share your code so we can understand what it is you're trying to ask - that would go a long way toward getting something more meaningful. I'm sure you've Googled and searched SO before posting, so your question has to be specific, yes?

Comment: ok that is very useful , I'm gonna share the code  i'v been writing, but i don't know if there's ok at all. @ShannonHolsinger

Answer (score 1):

You have a limit of 20 items the collection can hold, given the specified constructor of the `BlockingCollection`.

You put in 40 items, so after 20 items are added the methods will block.

Try to change to constructor to

```
static BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>(new ConcurrentQueue<int>(), 100);
```

and you will see it will then work.

To solve this you will need to make sure the consumer is taking items while the producers are adding items.

Since you do a `Task.WaitAll` on the producers it will wait until all items are added (which will never happen because after adding 20 items the next call to the `Add()` method will block, see the remarks section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287137(v=vs.110).aspx).

You will need to redesign your code so that consumers are taking items *while* producers are adding items or make sure the upperbound of the `BlockingCollection` is greater than the number of items you are adding before taking them.

In addition to your current code, replace the last line

```
Task.Run(() =>consuemr());
```

in

```
Task.Run(() =>consuemr()).Wait();
```

I get that in non-production code like this using .Wait() or .WaitAll() is not an issue but in production code you better use async .. await.

**Complete example**

I was hoping my hints gave you some idea on how to solve. Try this one:

```
class Program
{
    const int MAX_VALUE = 20;
    const int valueP = 0;
    static BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>(new ConcurrentQueue<int>(), 20);

    static void producer(int value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++)
        {
            bc.Add(value);

            value++;
            Console.WriteLine("Producing value {0}", value);
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(20);
    }

    static void Consumer()
    {
        foreach(var item in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An item has been consumed: {0}", item);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t1 =Task.Run(() => producer(valueP));
        Task t2 = Task.Run(() => producer(valueP));
        Task t3 = Task.Run(() => Consumer());

        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);

        bc.CompleteAdding(); // signal end of producing values

        t3.Wait(); // wait for consumer to read any unread values
    }
}
```

Consuming the items is now being done on a separate thread while the producers are adding items so the upperbound limit is not reached.

Another option is to instead of using `bc.CompleteAdding();` and `GetConsumingEnumerable()` you could use the `GetConsumingEnumerable` that takes a `CancellationToken` as a parameter to stop consuming items based on user input for example.

Also, this will work as well (replace existing code):

```
static void Consumer()
{
    int item;
    while(!bc.IsCompleted)
    {
        item = bc.Take();
        Console.WriteLine("An item has been consumed: {0}", item);
        Thread.Sleep(20);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t1 =Task.Run(() => producer(valueP));
    Task t2 = Task.Run(() => producer(valueP));
    Task t3 = Task.Run(() => Consumer());

    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);

    bc.CompleteAdding(); // signal end of producing values

    t3.Wait(); // wait for consumer to read any unread values
}
```

I hope this gives you a better idea. If you have a real world problem to solve please explain what else you need. Because there are numerous ways to read from a blocking collections but it depends on your specific situation.

Comment: Ok that is very useful  but i still don't know how could i do for having the consumer taking items while the producer is producing? @Peter Bons

Comment: that is what i was waiting for, really thank you!! since i want it to  only implement ti for practicing because i didn't know where i could start, thanks  man!!!  and well, just adding another consumer or producer is just as easy as adding another task  , isn't? @Peter Bons,

Comment: No problem, please mark my answer as the definitive answer when satisfied :-)